# HMAC authentication for REST

Tags: security, rest, hmac

I am looking to implment HMAC for my REST API based on

http://www.smartjava.org/content/protect-rest-service-using-hmac-play-20

The one thing I am still confused about is the how to get the SECRET to the client. The clients will be iphone, android and downloaded from the market

What I was thinking of was using something the user has entered as the SECRET like a pin, the server will have this pin via

1) client gets a public key from server
2) encrypts the pin with the public key
3) server stores pin in db
4) from that point forward the PIN in used as the SECRET

Any holes in this?

Comment: Can the secret derived from a password that is known by both parties ?

Comment: sorry not following, the PIN say 4 digits is entered by the client and encrypted with the public key. The server stores the plain text pin in the db. The client uses the PIN as the secret to calculate the HMAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would in principle be fine. However, a pin usually is only 4 digits. It would not be difficult for an attacker to get the public key and encrypt all 9999 combinations. He could then compare his encrypted keys with the encrypted data from the client and find the secret. You can avoid this problem by padding the pin with i.e. 50 random characters. The server must decrypt the padded data and simply throw away the last 50 characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hole.

At step 3, the PIN is stored in the database. The server has no way of knowing that the request to save the PIN comes from a legitimate user.

For this to work, you must save the PIN either :

- At account creation
- When the old PIN is provided

That being said, a PIN stays very weak and easy to break. A 4 digit pin will be guessed in about 5000 tries, on average.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a security expert, but what if the client sent along a random seed with each request?  Both the client and server would use this seed in generating a secret key based on a shared algorithm.  I'm not sure how attackable the relationship between a given seed and a returned hash would be, however.